# not returning anything in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

this is simple test for ajax and i want to send variable t in my index.php and get data(t) in my process.php and alert digit 15 when i click on button but my problem is not alerting anything

this is my index.php

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var t = 10;
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'process.php',
                data:{
                    't':t
                },
                success:(function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

```
<button id="btn">Click!</button>
```

this is my process.php

```
<?php
 $res = $_POST['t'] + 5;
 return $res
?>
```

Comment: Do you get any error in the console ?  also try add `error: function` and see what error you get there

Comment: Can you point to **any** example of generating a page response in PHP that uses `return` rather than outputting something? Please do thorough research before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change codes like below:-

1.jQuery:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var t = 10;
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'process.php',
            data:{'t':t},
            success:function (response) { //remove (
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

2.Php:-

```
<?php
 $res = $_POST['t'] + 5;
 echo  $res; //use echo rather than return
?>
```

***Reason:-***

`return` is used for returning a value from a function to another piece of `PHP` code.`jQuery` is not part of the execution of the `PHP` code on the server, so it has no idea what is really going on server side. `jQuery` is waiting for the rendered server response, which is what `echo` provides.

***Note:-*** After doing These changes, Please check the browser console while running the ajax and see any error happen there? If yes share with us

Comment: @sepehr  can you please check my edited answer. And please take care of `Note` section

Answer (score 1):

i) Change your code with following code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var t = 10;
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url:'process.php',
            data:{
                't':t
            },
            success:(function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }) //Close brace missing
        })
    })
});
```

2) Change **return** to **echo**

Comment: one close brace u missed in code. It should work. try it

Comment: What should the OP "change their code with the following code"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

          $("#btn").click(function (){
              var t = 10;
          $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url:'process.php',
                    data:{
                        t:t
                    },
                    success:(function (response) {
                        alert(response);

               // you didnt close )
                    }) // close of success
          })// close of ajax

        })// close of click

     }); // close of document
```

Process.php

```
<?php
 $res = $_POST['t'] + 5;
 echo $res;
?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You should add jQuery like this

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

If you actually have downloaded and placed the file in the same directory.

You can include in from a CDN if you don't want to download it. 
use this instead:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And fix your JS code: (remove the extra '}' ...)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var t = 10;
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'test.php',
                data:{
                    't':t
                },
                success:(function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                })
            })
        });
    });
```